Length of an additive functor is the supremum of lengths over all objects
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an additive category and $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Ab}$ an additive functor. We can define the length of $F$ as usual as the unique length of a composition series
$$0=F_n \subset ... \subset F_0=F$$
with $F_i/F_{i+1}$ simple if it exists. But, since $F$ is a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Ab}$, the quotient $F_i/F_{i+1}$ can be computed pointwise on each object. And thus, the length of $F$ should be the supremum of the lengths, i.e.
$$\ell(F)=\sup_{X \in \operatorname{ob}\mathcal{C}} \ell(F(X)).$$
My question is whether this is correct.
I have doubts because that would mean that a lot of functors have infinite length. For example, each inclusion functor
$$I_R: R\mathrm{-mod} \to \mathrm{Ab}$$
would have infinite length because $R^n$ has length $n$ and for each $n>0$ we have that $R^n$ is an object in $R\mathrm{-mod}$. And that all of these functors have infinite length seemed unintuitive to me.

I think there is an issue in your formula for $\ell(F)$.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, I edited it.

So a "simple functor" is one that is object-wise simple?

@Thorgott Well actually, by definition a simple functor is a functor which has exactly two subfunctors, i.e. two subobjects in the category of additive functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathrm{Ab}$. Since subobjects are computed pointwise, I think, your question can be affirmed.

There's still an issue with your formula for $\ell(F)$, as the right hand side is independent of $F$.

@JeremyRickard Right..., oops. Edited again

It depends what you mean by $\ell\left(F(X)\right)$.
If you mean the length as an abelian group, then there is little connection between the length of $F$ and the length of $F(X)$.
However, $F(X)$ has more structure. It inherits the structure of a left module over $\operatorname{End}(X)$, and if you mean the length of $F(X)$ as an $\operatorname{End}(X)$-module, then your formula is correct.
First, if $F$ is a simple functor, then for any object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$, $F(X)$ is either zero or simple as an $\operatorname{End}(X)$-module, since if $U$ is a proper nonzero $\operatorname{End}(X)$-submodule of $F(X)$, then it generates a proper nonzero subfunctor of $F$.
Now, if $F$ has a composition series
$$0=F_n \subset \cdots \subset F_0=F,$$
then, for each $i$ with $0\leq i<n$, choose an object $X_i$ of $\mathcal{C}$ such that $F_i(X_i)/F_{i+1}(X_i)$ is nonzero.
Then take $X=X_0\oplus\cdots\oplus X_{n-1}$, so that $F_i(X)/F_{i+1}(X)$ is nonzero, and hence simple as an $\operatorname{End}(X)$-module, for every $i$, and so $\ell\left(F(X)\right)=n$.
But finally, for all objects $Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$, $F_i(Y)/F_{i+1}(Y)$ is zero or simple as an $\operatorname{End}(Y)$-module, and so $\ell\left(F(Y)\right)\le n$.
